# Windows 7/10 Volume control bug

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, audio

i dont know if there is question like this but i want to ask. Why when i lower the volume on Media Player, it lowers even on the Media Player volume. If i lower the volume on the Volume control its like i lower from the Media Player. Before havent happened.  its like i want 100 Volume on the Volume Control and 10-15 on Media Player. Solutions on the way please :D.
It happened even on win7 and win10(after upgrading it fixed till' i restarted my pc)..

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a design decision, and is therefore not a bug (unintentional effect).  My recollection is that Windows Media Player has a volume control which may affect the system-wide settings.  I don't believe this was always the case, so this might be more true with some versions of Microsoft Windows Media Player (e.g., MS WiMP version 9) rather than earlier versions (e.g., Media Player 6.4).

Since this seems to be an intentional change by Microsoft, this is unlikely to be getting "fixed" by some random bugfix package.

If you don't like the behavior, well, welcome to the world of "closed source" software.  Choices include adapting (you, adapting yourself), or trying an older version to see if it worked different, or trying an open source alternative such as [MPC-HC](http://mpc-hc.org/) or [MPlayer (from MPlayerHQ.hu)](https://mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html) or [VLC Player](http://videolan.org/vlc)